# MSP430F5529 Address Decoding

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, msp430

If the CPU executes an instruction such as: mov 123h, addr

What is the CPU's decoding logic to determine if addr belongs to flash or RAM, does it care? If addr goes out on the addr bus, do certain memory modules ignore the write request if it knows the destination address isn't within range of it's mem map?

Answer (score 0):

1. The CPU itself does not decode addresses.
2. All modules ignore the access, except for the module whose address range matches.

Comment: How would, for ie, the ram module know that this is a valid memory address for it to take action on? What data table does it consult, if any?

Comment: Why a table? Each module has a lower and an upper address limit.